# How to correct http error 403 in twitter api

Tags: python, url, twitter, oauth

Trying to retrieve my friends status from my twitter account using python library for accessing web pages.
Giving me error:

> File "C:\Users\HP\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
import socket
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.twitter.com', 80))
cmd = 'GET https://twitter.com/bawo_nelson HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n context=ctx'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? Just the error isn't enough for us to fix it, but it's probably because you're not making an authenticated request.

Comment: import socket
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.twitter.com', 80))
cmd = 'GET https://twitter.com/bawo_nelson HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n context=ctx'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()                                                        
Thanks for your feedback